# Item Level Permissions not setting in sharepoint-online/Sharepoint 365 using Microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

According to the suggested answer in

[how to show items to users that made their requests but allow admins/managers to view all items in Sharepoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257003/how-to-show-items-to-users-that-made-their-requests-but-allow-admins-managers-to)

and

http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

I was able to get the access token, client id and client secret using Postman.

Now that I am trying to use them in HTTP connector of Microsoft Flow as stated in these:

https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2018/04/23/item-level-permissions-using-microsoft-flow/

https://noellawlor.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/setting-sharepoint-item-list-permissions-with-flow/

I find the **Get Access token** component as stated in both doesn't work in my flow. Here is the image:

[image]

Here's the error description which I am getting in the response json:

"error_description": "AADSTS500012: Resource application name '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/mycompany.sharepoint.com@3a505637-8fd6-4d12-b49f-409f1f13af04' is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: 66838e7c-4f81-4668-b1d6-e335284d8b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 359f6027-eeb2-4bbe-90a2-01bea0d178fe\r\nTimestamp: 2019-04-01 19:47:12Z",

or it says **Unauthorized** if I remove /human_resources from the request body resource parameter
[image]

I really have no idea why it is happening. I was able to fetch everything in Postman but it fails here in the Microsoft flow.

Comment: it seems strange that you get the unauthorized on the root. I recently had a problem with accessing bin and it came out to the issue that someone has deleted read permission to all authenticated users on the root site. Other question is your human resources created at this url or at sites\human_resources?

Comment: its like mycompany.sharepoint.com/human_resources. Yes it's one of the sites in mycompany page

Comment: Do I need to assign 'Read' permissions before asking for access token?

Comment: Well account that executes the WF should have an access; it wouldn't hurt to test.

Comment: Well most of the user groups have Full Control, Contribute and Read permissions on list items due to Permissions Hierarchy from parent site

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in this link:

https://sharepointmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2018/02/microsoft-flow-http-rest-api-invalid.html

There were the special characters in request body that had to be encoded for URI and that helped me obtain the access token for further steps

Answer (score 0):

In below link step by step item level permission explained:

https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/assign-unique-permissions-to-a-document-with-the-new-send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint-action-how-to-use-the-sharepoint-rest-api-in-flow/

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati